# TailwindCSS and Nuxt flex alignment on first and last element different

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a basic form with tailwind css within Nuxt. I have basic Nuxt components aligned in a flex using tailwind css classes.

[image]

```
<!-- basic form with 6 elemtns  but first and last elemnt -->
<!-- are aligned differently to the rest -->

<div class="flex justify-around p-8">
  <form class="grid grid-cols-2 p-8 space-y-4 space-x-4 rounded shadow bg-white">
    <NumberField label="Freight Cost" v-model="LCLState.cost" />
    <NumberField label="Shipments" v-model="LCLState.shipments" />
    <NumberField label="Per Shipment Fee" v-model="LCLState.perShipmentFee" />
    <NumberField label="Volume" v-model="LCLState.volume" />
    <NumberField label="Rate" v-model="LCLState.rate" />
    <PrimaryButton @click.prevent="calculateVolume()" title="Calculate Volume" width="w-40" :disabled="LCLState.rate === null" />
    <PrimaryButton @click.prevent="calculateRate()" title="Calculate Rate" width="w-40" :disabled="LCLState.volume === null" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Everything is working as expected, except the last and first elements seem to be left-middle aligned while all the other elements seem to be left-bottom aligned. I've tried to google the problem, but based on the nature of the question I get a whole bunch of unrelated answers.

Comment: Isn't this a matter of `align-items/justify-content`?

Comment: If you replace `space-y-4 space-x-4` with `gap-4` is it OK?